# "Save Photos in Photo albums of iPhone or iPad using Xamarin Forms" However PCL is Deprecated

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am trying do to the thing that is the question in this Stack Overflow Post "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49291495/save-photos-in-photo-albums-of-iphone-or-ipad-using-xamarin-forms". However in the answer for the post PCL is deprecated. What is a more updated answer? Thank you.

Comment: use a NetStandard library instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However in the answer for the post PCL is deprecated.

Actually , you just need to do the same thing in Share Projects . **DependencyService** is available in Xamarin.Forms , which you can refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction .

#### in Forms

```
public interface ISavePhotosToAlbum
{
    void SavePhotosWithStream(string name, Stream data);
}
```

#### in iOS

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(SaveToAlbum))]
namespace xxx.iOS
{
    public class SaveToAlbum : ISavePhotosToAlbum
    {
        public void SavePhotosWithStream(string name,Stream stream)
        {
            var imageData = NSData.FromStream(stream);
            var image = UIImage.LoadFromData(imageData);

            image.SaveToPhotosAlbum((img, error) =>
            {

            });
        }
    }
}
```

And add the following code in **info.plist**

```
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>App need to access your camera</string>
<key>NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription</key>
<string>App need to access your albums</string>  // new in iOS 11 and later
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>App need to access your albums</string>
```

In addition , if you want to implement it in Android

#### in Android

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(SaveToAlbum))]
namespace xxx.Droid
{
    public class SaveToAlbum : ISavePhotosToAlbum
    {
        public void SavePhotosWithStream(string name,Stream stream)
        {
            var documentsPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
            documentsPath = Path.Combine(documentsPath, "Orders", temp);
            Directory.CreateDirectory(documentsPath);

            string filePath = Path.Combine(documentsPath, name);

            byte[] bArray = new byte[data.Length];
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath , FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
            {
                using (data)
                {
                    data.Read(bArray, 0, (int)data.Length);
                }
                int length = bArray.Length;
                fs.Write(bArray, 0, length);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Zhang Thank you it worked. I did not realize that I had to make a c sharp file in my project and put the interface in there.